# Can't convert Iterators into js_sys::Array

Tags: arrays, rust, iterator, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to implement a method to send an array of `u32` (eventually an array *of* arrays of `usize`, if possible), since you can't just declare a public array field on a `wasm_bindgen` type. However, using the example outlined in the `wasm_bindgen` [PR 1749](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/pull/1749), I can't seem to convert arrays or slices to a `js_sys::Array`; it only works for `Vec`s. My question is, why? See below

```
pub fn test() -> js_sys::Array {
    let arr: [u32; 5] = [0,1,2,3,4];
    let slice = &arr[0..2];
    let vec: Vec<u32> = vec![0,1,2];
    arr.into_iter().map(JsValue::from).collect() // This doesn't work
    slice.into_iter().map(JsValue::from).collect() // Also doesn't work
    vec.into_iter().map(JsValue::from).collect() // Works as expected!     
}
```

The specific error is: `the trait 'wasm_bindgen::cast::JsCast' is not implemented for 'u32'`

The array and slice examples don't seem to work for any number type, ints or floats. My only thought is because the implementation in PR 1749 seems to expect a ref, and arrays are allocated on the stack that the `FromIterator` is not valid for items in an array?

Is there some other way to achieve what I'm trying to do with the array (passing across the boundary to JS through `wasm_bindgen`), or if not, why? I'd be very interested to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Rust arrays and slices have an `into_iter` method it returns the same `Iterator` as the `iter` method does which iterates over *references* to values instead of the values themselves. Yes, this is confusing. Since `JsValue::from` is implemented for `u32` but not for `&u32` you can take your `Iterator<Item = &u32>` and convert it to a `Iterator<Item = u32>` using the `copied` method. Fixed working examples:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::JsValue;
use js_sys::Array;

fn array_to_js_array(array: [u32; 5]) -> Array {
    array.iter().copied().map(JsValue::from).collect()     
}

fn slice_to_js_array(slice: &[u32]) -> Array {
    slice.iter().copied().map(JsValue::from).collect()    
}

fn vec_to_js_array(vec: Vec<u32>) -> Array {
    vec.into_iter().map(JsValue::from).collect()    
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `into_iter` behaved differently for arrays (and slices) than it does for `vec`. That explains it! Thanks. I now notice that the linter flags `into_iter` for arrays (not slices) and says this will soon be a hard error, so I guess this ambiguity is being addressed. Would be nice to have a single method for arrays that does what `into_iter` does for `vec`, but I'm sure there's a reason it's this way.